# How do you remove the dotted outline in Firefox links WITHOUT harming accessibility?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

There are many questions/answers about how to remove the dotted outline on javascript / ajax links in Firefox, but they all recommend setting the outline property to 0, which harms accessibility. Moreover, it skirts the issue: Firefox focus behavior is the issue, not how the focus is styled.

In Chrome, clicking an ajax link does not produce focus. It only starts to focus when you begin tabbing. Firefox on the other hand, aggressively places focus when you click the mouse.

Is there a way to get Firefox to behave more like chrome when it comes to focus being set by mouse clicks, without having to sacrifice accessibility by setting `outline` to `none` or `0`.

Example of this effect can be seen on `http://news.yahoo.com`. In FF if you down click the links on the left (but move your mouse off the link before click release), you'll see the dotted outline. In chrome if you do the same, you won't see the outline, but you will once you start hitting `tab`.

Is there any way to force FF to have a similar behavior?

And a related question: how do you consistently reproduce this dotted outline behavior in Firefox? Firefox does not seem to do this with all links, and it appears to happen only under certain circumstances.

For instance, most links on StackOverflow do not have this issue, despite not having an `outline` override.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior everywhere on Firefox. Typically Firefox focuses links when you activate them (i.e. click on them). Apparently, Chrome does not.

Comment: I can't for some reason:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQoMqv

Those links do not exhibit this behavior in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need is to suppress the outline on links that are currently being clicked on.

```css
a:active {outline:none}
```

```html
<p><a href="#1">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#2">Link 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#3">Link 3</a></p>
<p><a href="#4">Link 4</a></p>
```

If this is not it, please let me know and we can work towards a more complete solution!

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. The links I'm working with are ajax links. After you click them, the active state no longer applies, but firefox still considers them focused since the page does not refresh. Setting `a:focus { outline:none }` solves the issue, except it ruins accessibility in Chrome because the element no longer displays chrome's default blue focus outline when tabbing.

Comment: @AgmLauncher Can you provide a demo that shows the issue, as a stack snippet in your question? Or if that won't work, a link to your webpage.

Comment: This is an internal tool so unfortunately I can't link to it, and Firefox does not seem to exhibit this behavior on all links. It does on the http://news.yahoo.com example I posted above (links on the left), but I cannot seem to force FF to behave that way, thus it's making trying out different fixes very difficult.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you want. If I edit the Yahoo page and add my CSS in, the news links won't have outlines when you press down the mouse button, only on completion of the click. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
a::-moz-focus-inner
{
    outline: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

The border-color is the dotted thing in firefox, yes that makes no sense but that's like that.